# Why does try exits after first statement if it throws an Exception?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I am new to python I am learning exception handling now.

```
try:
    print(1/0)
    int(input("number"))
    import bala
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Divided by zero")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("dont press ctrl C!")
except ValueError:
    print("Value should be number")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("Module not found")
```

The above code exits after first exception and the rest of the `try` statements are not executed. Should I use separate try-except block for each statement? Like this

```
try:
    int(input("number"))
except ValueError:
    print("Value should be number")
```

and

```
try:
    import bala
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("Module not found")
```

Comment: You should if you want to continue with your code. In many cases it doesn't make sense since each line of code is dependent on the lines above. For example, if I have an exception opening a file, it makes no sense to then try to read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an exception is raised that makes Python stop the execution *immediately*. You can prevent a complete program stop by using a `try` and `except`. However if an exception is raised in the `try` block, it will still stop execution right there and only continue if an appropriate `except` block catches the Exception (or if there is a `finally` block).

In short: If you want to continue with the next statements you need to use separate `try` and `except` blocks. But if you want to execute the next statements *only* if the previous statements didn't raise an Exception you shouldn't use separate `try` and `except` blocks.

Comment: A minor point, it should be: execute the next statements only if the prior ones work... Someone could be confused into thinking the block is atomic.

Comment: @ivo That's right. I edited it to avoid the ambiguity. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have separate exception blocks because if it gets by the first block, it thinks thats all it needs to get by, so if you want to test every one, you should use separate ones

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multiple try/except blocks.

Once an error is found, anything happening is stopped, and the exception is dealed with.

Think of it as a fire. When there is a fire you stop whatever and run out. For python it deals with the exception